# Why $\mathbb{D}^2 / \mathbb{S}^1 = \mathbb{S}^2$?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $\mathbb{D}^2$ be the closed planar unit disk, $\mathbb{D}^2 = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$, and let $\mathbb{S}^1$ be the  boundary circle, $\mathbb{S}^1 = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 +y^2 = 1\}$.

Why $\sim$ such that $\mathbb{D}^2 / \mathbb{S}^1 = \mathbb{S}^2$?

$\mathbb{S}^2$ denotes the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

My attempt:

Define an equivalence relation $\thicksim$ whose equivalence class of a point $(x, y)$ is $\{(x,y)\}$ when $(x, y) \not\in \mathbb{S}^1$ and $(x,y) \thicksim (1,0)$  whenever $(x,y) \in \mathbb{S}^1$. Is $\mathbb{D}^2/ \sim = \mathbb{S}^2$?

Please help me.

Comment: I don't understand how the equivalence has to be defined on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ as you're dealing with $\mathbb S^1$?

Comment: This might be a good time to review our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). Your question is just a problem statement with no context, and as you may have experienced, is likely to attract close votes.

Comment: Did you ever blow up a balloon and close it with a knot?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff This look like a sphere, but what is the proof? Is there any?

Comment: A way to proceed is to find a map $D^2\to S^2$ that is injective away from the boundary and maps the boundary to the North Pole of $S^2$. Can you think of any such map?

Comment: If you remove the boundary class from the quotient you’re left with the plane, essentially. Just as with the sphere.